# Como retornar determinado valor de um array

Tags: javascript

Estou com um projeto de tradutor de texto simples, aonde ao usuario digirar determinada palavra,
se ela existir no array ele retorna o segundo valor do array, por exemplo, o usuario digita AMOR, e seu retorno será LOVE. Porem não encontrei uma maneira de Caso ele digite o LOVE o retorno seja AMOR. Segue o script abaixo

```js
//Translate
    (function () {
        //filter
        function setFilter() {
            var result = [];
            var filterOnInput = document.querySelector('.filter_translate').value;
            data.forEach((element) => {
                if (element.q.toString() == filterOnInput) {
                    result.push(element);
                } else if (element.a.toString() == filterOnInput) {

                };
            });

            document.querySelector('.result_translate').innerHTML = result[0]?.a;
            let m = document.querySelector('.result_translate'),
                n = m.textContent;
            if (n == 'undefined') {
                m.innerHTML = '<img src=/image/load-i.gif>';
                m.style.cursor = 'pointer'
            }

            if (filterOnInput == '') {
                m.innerHTML = 'Resultados';
            };
        };

        //Remove load
        onclick = (y) => {
            let a = document.querySelector('.translate__fast'),
                b = document.querySelector('.translate__fast div'),
                c = document.querySelector('.translate__fast h2'),
                d = document.querySelector('.translate__fast h3'),
                e = document.querySelector('.translate__fast p'),
                f = document.querySelector('.translate__fast input');
            if (y.target != a && y.target != b && y.target != c && y.target != d && y.target != e && y.target != f) {
                f.value = '';
                e.innerHTML = 'Resultados';
            }
        };

        //keyup
        function onload() {
            var el = document.querySelector('.filter_translate');

            el.addEventListener('keyup', function (t) {
                setFilter();
                var t = el.value;
                t = t.toLowerCase().replace(/(?:^|\s)\S/g, function (capitalize) {
                    return capitalize.toLowerCase();
                });
                el.value = t;
            }, false);

        };

        onload();
        //Translate Content
        var data = [
            {
                "q": 'abet',
                "a": 'Instigar<audio src="a1.wav"></audio>',
            },
            {
                "q": 'amor',
                "a": 'love<audio src="a1.wav"></audio>',
            },
        ];
    })();
```

```html
<!-- TRANSLATE -->
        <section class="translate__fast">
            <span class="cor">
                <figure></figure>
            </span>
            <div class="dv_trnaslate_ft">
                <h2>Tradutor</h2>
                <input type="text" class="filter_translate" placeholder="Pesquisar">
                <div class="rr__tr_">
                    <p class="result_translate sounds">Resultados<audio src=""></audio></p>
                </div>
                <p>Um click para ouvir, dois para copiar</p>
            </div>
        </section>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eu ajustei o código para funcionar com um idioma ou com o outro.
Contudo, no seu array não deve contar a tag de audio. Não dessa forma de pesquisa.

No código eu adicionei uma verificação de qual idioma está sendo pesquisado. Se for um eu pesquiso o a do array, se for outro eu pesquiso o q do array.
Ainda tirei a tag de audio la do array.

Olha se isso consegue lhe dar um direcionamento para o que precisa.

```js
//Translate
        (function () {
            //filter
            function setFilter() {
                var result = [];
                var language = 1;
                var filterOnInput = document.querySelector('.filter_translate').value;
                data.forEach((element) => {
                    if (element.q.toString() == filterOnInput) {
                        result.push(element);
                        language = 1;
                    } else if (element.a.toString() == filterOnInput) {
                        result.push(element);
                        language = 2;
                    };
                });

                if(language === 1){
                    document.querySelector('.result_translate').innerHTML = result[0]?.a;
                }
                else if(language === 2) {
                    document.querySelector('.result_translate').innerHTML = result[0]?.q;
                }
                
                let m = document.querySelector('.result_translate'),
                    n = m.textContent;
                if (n == 'undefined') {
                    m.innerHTML = '<img src=/image/load-i.gif>';
                    m.style.cursor = 'pointer'
                }

                if (filterOnInput == '') {
                    m.innerHTML = 'Resultados';
                };
            };

            //Remove load
            onclick = (y) => {
                let a = document.querySelector('.translate__fast'),
                    b = document.querySelector('.translate__fast div'),
                    c = document.querySelector('.translate__fast h2'),
                    d = document.querySelector('.translate__fast h3'),
                    e = document.querySelector('.translate__fast p'),
                    f = document.querySelector('.translate__fast input');
                if (y.target != a && y.target != b && y.target != c && y.target != d && y.target != e && y.target != f) {
                    f.value = '';
                    e.innerHTML = 'Resultados';
                }
            };

            //keyup
            function onload() {
                var el = document.querySelector('.filter_translate');

                el.addEventListener('keyup', function (t) {
                    setFilter();
                    var t = el.value;
                    t = t.toLowerCase().replace(/(?:^|\s)\S/g, function (capitalize) {
                        return capitalize.toLowerCase();
                    });
                    el.value = t;
                }, false);

            };

            onload();
            //Translate Content
            var data = [
                {
                    "q": 'abet',
                    "a": 'instigar',
                },
                {
                    "q": 'amor',
                    "a": 'love',
                },
            ];
        })();
```

```html
    <!-- TRANSLATE -->
            <section class="translate__fast">
                <span class="cor">
                    <figure></figure>
                </span>
                <div class="dv_trnaslate_ft">
                    <h2>Tradutor</h2>
                    <input type="text" class="filter_translate" placeholder="Pesquisar">
                    <div class="rr__tr_">
                        <p class="result_translate sounds">Resultados<audio src=""></audio></p>
                    </div>
                    <p>Um click para ouvir, dois para copiar</p>
                </div>
            </section>
```